# lstlistings in defined Tikz box

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, listings

I have created a box using `\newcommand`, based on TikZ named "mybox". The equation easily insertable in it. But I want to insert a `\lstlisting` environment in it. But it doesn't work. How can I do it? Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{times}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand*\mybox[1]{\centering\tikz{\node [text width=15cm,rounded corners,fill=orange!50,inner sep=0.5ex,midway](char){#1};}}

\begin{document}

\mybox{

\begin{equation}

\int_S \mathbf{B}\cdot d\mathbf{s}

\end{equation}

}

\mybox{

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single,language=PHP,caption=Php info\label{php_info}]
<?php
phpinfo();
?>

\end{lstlisting}

}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, I would suggest you using the [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package to create the colored frame; the package offers the `listings` library and the `tcblisting` environment to let you use the features from the `listings` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand*\mybox[1]{\centering\tikz{\node [text width=15cm,rounded corners,fill=orange!50,inner sep=0.5ex,midway](char){#1};}}

\begin{document}

\mybox{%
\begin{equation}
\int_S \mathbf{B}\cdot d\mathbf{s}
\end{equation}%
}

\begin{tcblisting}{listing only,listing options={frame=single,language=PHP,caption=Php info,label={php_info}},
colback=orange!50,boxrule=0pt,width=\dimexpr15cm+1ex\relax}
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If this construct is going to be used several times, it is better to use `\newtcblisting` to define an environment with the predefined options; something along these lines (the optional argument for the `lisbox` environment allows to pass additional options to the listings options)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{lisbox}[1][]{%
  listing only,
  listing options={frame=single,language=PHP,#1},
  colback=orange!50,
  boxrule=0pt,
  width=15cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{lisbox}[caption=Php info,label={php_info}]
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
\end{lisbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quicky answer and facing me with tcblisting.

Comment: @ferahfeza You're welcome! I updated my answer with a new code that might be useful.

Comment: @Medina, This is also nice and clean code. Thanks.